# Discord.py Как сделать отправку личных сообщений новым пользователям. По типу приветствия

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Помогите с отправкой личных сообщений
Как делать эту команду на то чтоб она отправляла в лс не по команде, а при заходе нового пользователя?
Команда работает и все отправляет, нужно только исправить на то чтоб отправляла при подключении.

Мне помогли с кодом. Спасибо всем кто не остался равнодушным.
Знаю еще много людей будет искать такой код, поэтому вот код

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'],  intents=intents) #Без этих трех команд не работает

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    #now = datetime.now()
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Добро пожаловать на DrainProject', color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name="Если не знаешь что делать", value='К твоему прочтению обязателен канал <#965359487416418306>. (Галочка в конце)', inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="Также чтоб не было притензий и разногласий", value='Тебе необходимо прочитать канал <#927297696761528392>', inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name= "Команды бота", value='Чтоб узнать подробнее команды пропиши !help в канале <#972431181624791060>', inline=False)
    emb.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    #emb.set_footer(text=f'Ваш ID: {member.id} • {now.hour}:{now.minute}')
    await member.send(embed = emb)
```

[!Для тех кто думает что эмбеды не отправляются](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CYhY.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CYhY.png)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord Server!')
Не работает данная команда

Comment: вероятно, у вас не включены и не выданы [**намерения**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) или у `member` закрыты личные сообщения

Comment: Нет, все включенно, я просто не пойму как переписать код.

Comment: я пробовал другой код, но он не работает
`bot.event()
async def on_member_join(member):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}(текст)')`

Answer (score 1):

Я написал свой код для приветствия нового участника и у меня всё работает(кстати про отправку эмбедов я действительно не знал), попробуйте скопировать мой код и отредактировать
Скорее всего ошибка в том, что после @bot.event не требуются скобки.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    now = datetime.now()

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Добро пожаловать на "Тестовый сервер"!',
        description='',
        color=0x0000FF
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Ваш ID: {member.id} • {now.hour}:{now.minute}')

    await member.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а через ембед чтоб?

Comment: код не рабочий, я пробовал уже, он не отправляет, даже если лс открыто. интенты все включено, через команду потому что которую я написал он работает, а через этот код нет

Comment: Эмбеды в личное сообщение не отправляются. Я затестил код у себя в боте и он работал, ищите проблему со своей стороны.

Comment: да ладно, показать скрин?

Comment: Дополнил скриншотом свой вопрос где отправляется эмбед

Comment: Ну так, у вас на скриншоте он отправился, в чём проблема?

Comment: Это через команду которая самая первая,
А через вторую, которая переделанна на то чтоб пользователю отправлялось при заходе на сервер, она не работает, не знаю в чем проблема

Comment: Интенты включены?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ выше пожалуйста, у меня ответ да не помещался просто

Comment: Я отредактировал свой ответ, попробуй скопировать код и под себя поменять, у меня всё работает. Либо что-то в коде. либо какая проблема у вас.

Comment: Я понял в чём ошибка, после @bot.event не нужны скобки, они нужны только в @bot.command()

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ты мой спаситель, я прям на 7 небе от счастья, сча буду тестить <3

Comment: Он тоже не работает(((
не переделанный
не ваш
сейчас дополню свой вопрос еще одним кодом, покажу как переделал ваш код

Comment: Я даже новый аккаунт зарегистрировал, но он не работает

Comment: может библиотеки какой то нет, сейчас дополню покажу все библиотеки

Comment: внизу библиотеки, а чуть выше код переделанный

Comment: Потому что ты мой код копировал и там осталось, embed.add_author и embed.add_footer, а у тебя вводится переменная emb, поменяй embed на emb

Comment: так и сделал дружище, я это тоже заметил, но результата ноль, у друга код работает, а у меня ивент не видит, переделали код под то чтоб видел, у друга работает снова, у меня нет

Comment: я разобрался, спасибо за помощь